# Installing Timescaledb on Mac OS X, PostgreSQL 9.6 not found

Tags: macos, postgresql, time-series, timescaledb

I am trying to install Timescaledb on my Mac, http://docs.timescale.com/getting-started/installation?OS=mac&method=Source. The requirement for this is PostgreSQL 9.6 so I downloaded the postgres.app. However, when I try to build and install `timescaledb`- I get the following error:

```
Z-MBP:~ user$ cd timescaledb
Z-MBP:timescaledb user$ make
/bin/sh: pg_config: command not found
Makefile:6: *** "TimescaleDB requires PostgreSQL 9.6".  Stop.
```

But postgres.app is installed and the server is running fine. What is going wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Makefile is telling you that it can't find `pg_config`.

As postgres.app is supposed to include this CLI utility in its [install](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp#command-line-utilities), my first guess is that you don't have the utility in your $PATH.

I think you asked same question on TimescaleDB's github issues page, and given the ongoing Q&A there, thought to just point readers to that:

https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/156